# Browsing server machine file system

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat

i got 2 machines a server and a client . so from my client host the administrator of my application should choose a directory on the server , so  i want to browse the server file system from the client host . After choosing a directory on the server i'll create a folder in that directory and use it to run cammand lines...

So how to implement browsing server machine file system ?

Comment: If you ask such a question, you should read the FAQ again...

Comment: This is not possible unless you create your own OS/FileSystem which allows remote client to access files on your local machine, because this will be a huge security loophole

Comment: but I wonder whether such FS exists? because I have heard people accessing mobile files through bluetooth. Or I also know about network sharing in windows which allows you to access remote machine in network if they are connected and shared. Just not sure about how is it possible through java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not directly possible because of the security restrictions. 
But you can workaround the restrictions by writing a bean class which holds the file system information so that a special self-made FileSelectDialog can show these information to the user via the webfrontend.

In the Glassfish Admin GUI they've have done something similar...under **Applications --> Deploy** you can select files from your local filesystem or from the server file system via a special file selection dialog.

Another approach is documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984777/how-to-browse-the-file-system-of-a-server-machine-when-connecting-with-a-client)